# don't display value in listgrid

Tags: gwt, grid, smartgwt

I use smartgwt to display a grid.
In the record, i have some data who are true or false.
I change de background color in the getBaseStyle method for the listGrid that work well.

Now, i don't want to display the value true or false in the cell.

I can put the text color the same than background, but it's very bad.

Any idea?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add another listGridField to the listGrid whose background color depends on the value of this booleanfield. This field wont have any text to display. Then you hide the boolean field in the listgrid.